# what is the native?

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code

eos/chain/apply_context.cpp 66 line

i had been found the something where account_name newly was created like eosio.token, eosio.rex....

So, i found some hint

```
controller.cpp // 321 Line
#define SET_APP_HANDLER( receiver, contract, action) \
set_apply_handler( #receiver, #contract, #action, &BOOST_PP_CAT(apply_, BOOST_PP_CAT(contract, BOOST_PP_CAT(_,action) ) ) )
```

first, the set_apply_handler set the handler. and when i create a account, account data must go throuh the following code

```
     auto native = control.find_apply_handler( receiver, act->account, act->name );
     if( native ) {
        if( trx_context.enforce_whiteblacklist && control.is_producing_block() ) {
           control.check_contract_list( receiver );
           control.check_action_list( act->account, act->name );
        }
        (*native)( *this );
     }
```

and the (*native)(*this) code is trigger a function

```
eosio_contract.cpp // 71 line
void apply_eosio_newaccount(){
    const auto &new_account = db.create<account_object>([&](auto &a) {
        a.name = create.name;
        a.creation_date = context.control.pending_block_time();
});
....
}
```

but how can use the (*native)(*this) and how operate the code??